# Ventilation fan in bathroom slower level

Tags: capacitor, fan

[image]

I just changed control switch and box with (2 capacitators in it) to my fan in the bathroom. The fan is in bathroom above shower and has a 4 uf capacitator stuck to it.

Level 1 seems slower than before after changing the switch box. Level 2 and 3 seems high and okay. I guess it was a 4 uf in the old box (box is handled as waste and i cant check).

I am thinking about maybe increasing the level 1 so that i can get closer to what i think was 60 V before, and now is 50 V and too slow for keeping good ventilation. How much effect do you think it will give me if I change capacitator from 3 to 4 uf ? And will it only affect level 1?

[image: wiring instruction for switch and switchbox connectedfan 155w to the fan]

Answer (score 0):

3uF to 4uf:

How much difference?  About 20 to 25% I would expect.

Changing to 6uF would presumably get you the current mid speed.

Instead of replacing you can add capacitors in parallel (assuming there's room and a suitable way to make the connection) add 1uF parallel to 3uF to get 4uf.

Comment: Thanks! Its only space for the two capacitors in the box, so I need to replace I think. So Then Capacitor from 1-4 on the wire diagram above will be changed from 3 uf to 4uf. Hopefully thaht give about 25 % more power on the fans lowest level (0-1 which is basic ventilation). Do you think I should change the other capacitor in the box to 4 uf as well? As far as I know this will only affect the fan speed at level 2 and 3? Or is it fine with that beeing 3uf and the capacitor to level 0-1 beeing 4 uf?